# Angular Test only works with mock service class but not value

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript

I have the following angular (4) component test. In the component, there is a line `this.jobService.subscribeEvent('thisline')`.

```
class MockJobService {
  public subscribeEvent(line: string): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.of({ action: 'dwnTime' } })
  }
}

describe('NotificationComponent', () => {
  let component: NotificationComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<NotificationComponent>;
  let mockJobService = new MockJobService();

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [NotificationComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: JobService, useValue: mockJobService }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
```

When I run this test I get the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

However, if I change the test to include this line: `{ provide: JobService, useClass: MockJobService }`. Then the tests work, however, I want to run a spy on the `subscribeEvent` function and I need the `useValue` version to work. Any ideas what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spying a method does not call the actual method: https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html

That's why you're getting the

> Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

cause you're not returning the Observable and the Observer has nothing to subscribe.

Add the following option to the spy so the internal method can be called:

```
spyOn(component.mockJobService, 'subscribeEvent').and.callThrough()
```

Or alternatively, define a fake function to be called:

```
spyOn(component.mockJobService, 'subscribeEvent').and.callFake(myFunction)
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the implementation of original service, posted code cannot explain why the error can appear.

useValue and useClass are interchangeable in such cases, but `new MockJobService()` should be placed inside `beforeEach` in order for them to be equal. It's always better to work with fresh objects.

Service methods can also be spied with useClass too:

```
spyOn(MockJobService.prototype, 'subscribeEvent').and...
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for the very specific question asked by the OP. In order to leverage `useValue` with an object, it must be instantiated in `beforeEach` and prior to usage, otherwise that error listed will be encountered. With `useClass` that won't happen.